# xml suspect too many nested layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

I made an app and it worked good on the devices that it was tested,but on the other devices when open a `layout` with many fields it crush and receive an  error I modified same fields but I think that is not enough,this is the error and I put the `xml` file too

```
      java.lang.StackOverflowError
      at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:416)
      at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:295)
      at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:269)
      at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:942)
      at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:405)
      at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
      at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5295)
      at android.widget.CompoundButton.onDraw(CompoundButton.java:241)
      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11167)
      at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10606)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2863)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2502)
      at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10604)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2863)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2502)
      at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10604)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2863)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2502)
```

and that is my `xml`:

```
       <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="5dp" >


<LinearLayout
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="0dip" 
android:layout_height="0dip"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/marca"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMarcaAuto"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="MODEL AUTO"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ModelAuto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="CATEGORIE AUTVEHICUL"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioCategorie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:text="Autoturism"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Autoturism de teren"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

     <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:text="Motocicleta"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"/>/>


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/alteleCategAuto"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/altele_button"
         android:paddingBottom="18dp" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="#C9C9C9" />      

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="JUDET,LOCALITATE TALON"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtJudLocTalon"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="NR. INMATRICULARE"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNrInmatriculare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SERIE SASIU"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wrong_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/exclamare_atentionare" />
</RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSerieSasiu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="CM3"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCM3"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Putere (kW)"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPutere"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="NUMAR LOCURI"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNumarLocuri"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="MASA MAXIMA (kg)"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMasaMaxima"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="AN FABRICATIE"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtAnFabricatie"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:inputType="number|textCapWords"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />




       <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SERIE TALON"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wrong_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/exclamare_atentionare" />
</RelativeLayout>

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_SerieTalon"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="DESTINATIE AUTO"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioDestinatieAuto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:text="interes-personal"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:text="distributie-marfa"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

     <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/radio_6"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="17dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:text="taxi"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"/>


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/alteleDestinatie"
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/altele_button"
         android:paddingBottom="18dp" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C9C9C9" /> 

         <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="COMBUSTIBIL"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioCombustibil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="benzina"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="motorina"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_radio_masina"
        android:button="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="gpl"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alteleCombustibil"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/altele_button"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

      <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#C9C9C9" />

     <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="AUTO IN LEASING?"
    android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/da_rca"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:text="DA"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/da_nu_nu_da_rca" />
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/nu_rca"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:text="NU"
         android:background="@drawable/da_nu_nu_nu_rca" />

     </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#C9C9C9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDenumireFirmaLeasing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="DENUMIRE FIRMA LEASING"
        android:textColor="@color/MenuDarkGrey"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtDenumireFirmaLeasing"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorTitlu"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />






    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/renunta_masina"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Renunta"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/MenuLightGrey"
                android:background="@drawable/button_renunta" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/salveaza_masina"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Salveaza"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:textColor="@color/MenuLightGrey"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button_salveaza" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this
Split your code into different xmls then

1. Use Fragments

   refer [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) documentation and  [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) tutorial
2. Use `<include>` tag

   refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) documentation for the same